# how to automate sending unique pdf documents to 100 recipients in docusign

Tags: automation, docusignapi

I need to automate sending multiple pdf documents (one needs a signature) to 150 recipients using docusign. I have looked through the documentation but not getting anywhere.  Appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thanks.

I have looked through docusign's documentation but could not find how to automate this. As per the documentation, one document can be sent to multiple recipients.  In my case one of the pdf document is unique to a recipient and the other is common to all recipients which needs a docusign.

Answer (score 0):

So, the process known as "[bulk sending](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/bulk-send-envelopes/)" can be used to send similar docs to many recipients. I say similar, because if the changes are minor, you can do them by using [custom fields](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopecustomfields/create/), tabs or some other mechanism (Say you just need a different amount in each doc, but everything else is the same).

However, if you truly need 150 recipients to get 150 different documents, you cannot use bulk send.

In that case, you have to just create 150 [envelopes](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/envelopes/) from your code. You can use a loop to iterate and just create them one at a time. If you can [create one](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-remote/), you can create 150, it's just a matter of fetching your [documents](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/documents/) and [recipients](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/recipients/) from a database of something and going in a loop.

Comment: Thanks @Inbar-Gazit.  Appreciate your response.  Can you please elaborate what you mean by code.

Comment: I mean to write an integration using the DocuSign eSignature API. See https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-remote/ for example